# Why isn't my Controller working but throwing a FileLoaderException?

Tags: php, symfony, routes, annotations

I have setup a new Controller and when I run

```
./app/console router:debug
```

I get the error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\FileLoaderLoadException]                                                                                                                                               
  Cannot import resource "/home/dev/Workspace/src/Hn/AssetDbBundle/Controller/" from "/home/dev/Workspace/app/config/routing.yml". ([Syntax Error] Expected PlainValue, got ''' at position 26 in method Hn\AssetDbBundle\Controller\Component\UnsupportedBrowserController::renderUnsupportedBrowserMessageAction().)
```

My Controller looks like this:

```
<?php
namespace Hn\AssetDbBundle\Controller\Component;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

/**
 * Class UnsupportedBrowserController
 * @Route("/_internal/browser/", name="component_browser")
 * 
 */
class UnsupportedBrowserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Template()
     * @Route('unsupported')
     */
    public function renderUnsupportedBrowserMessageAction()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Annotations require the use of double quotes, in this case:

```
* @Route("unsupported")
```

The single quotes throw the error as it complains via: `Expected PlainValue, got ''' at position 26`